# Give an example of a metric space (X, d), A, B ⊆ X such that A °= B °= ∅ but (A ∪ B) ° = X.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Give an example of a metric space (X, d), A, B ⊆ X such that A °= B °= ∅ .I can't come up with an example for this

Comment: HINT: It’s possible with $X=\Bbb R$ and $d$ the usual metric on $\Bbb R$. You want two complementary sets that both have lots and lots of ‘holes’.

Comment: Think *rationally*, and you'll figure it out...